# What is the best app for alert notifications in a IT environment

Tags: android, server, notification

What is the best app for alert notifications in an IT environment? We have been using Telegram so far, but I have gotten complaints about it.

We use it for programs like Splunk or Zabbix and a few others that send out alerts when things are not working as expected.

What we like to have:

- The possibility to connect directly to other programs (like Zabbix or Splunk)
- Easy to set up
- Preferably a web environment

What would be nice:

- Also connect to an exchange mailbox, so if there is a new email, a notification is sent out
- That we can take ownership of the alert and acknowledge it once it is fixed
- That we can use a plugin that will also notify us when we are working on our PC (via Chrome add-on for example)
- That it is running in the cloud

So far I have found Opsgenie, Signl4, and Pushover, but googling my question doesn't give me the right options.

Comment: Depending everything on a mailbox is IMHO a bad idea. If your mailserver is down would result in all notifications to not work.

Comment: Good point, I have adjusted the questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lot of software for this purpose. But check these below:

- Microsoft teams - work with free accounts, offer API for external
  communication, have desktop, mobile, web version
- Slack - team chat space, also offer API (up to 10 providers in free
  version)
- Discord - start as game chat, but offer very good audio, offered for
  a lot of platform, not sure about API, but offer a lot of bots and
  apps

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to do this I set up a "monitoring environment" that had;

- *[Any application at all]* with **Prometheus** Exporting
- Prometheus then feeds into **Grafana**
- Grafana can make a nice Dashboard and Alerts that get sent to...
- **Discord**!  On your phone :D  Or anywhere else!

Theoretically, you could create your own Prometheus formatted export of any information you wanted.  It's get a bit scary if you have to write it yourself but here's how; https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/

So as your requirements go;

- Connect to other programs - Check!  (If you're willing to write the
  exporter)
- Easy to set up - Everything's easy when you know how :
- Web env - Yes sir!
- Email notifications - Well that's something you can
  write with a Prometheus exporter and outlook, I would assume.  Find
  any way to handle that email event and you can write a metric.
- Ownership of alert - Maybe if you're using Jira or TFS you could add
  a webhook address to automatically add a task?
- In the cloud - Just
  put it on a server xD

Good luck!

p.s.  For email notification handling, see https://clusteringformeremortals.com/2018/10/28/step-by-step-how-to-trigger-an-email-alert-from-a-windows-event-that-includes-the-event-details-using-windows-server-2016/ for a decent guide (I haven't tested it)